# Highcharts double pie graphic strange rendering

Tags: highcharts

I've recently upgraded to the latest version of Highcharts v3.0.2 and now one of my existing charts is rendering in a strange manner. See 'Sector Chart' at this link 
http://bit.ly/10hU8TW

The circles seem narrow and out of alignment. Can anybody point me in the right direction to solve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at v3 configuration of http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut